# On a parametrization of an infinite series to recover the GARCH process

Tags: time-series, self-study, arma, garch

*Time series analysis* By James D. Hamilton (a great book) proceeds in this way to introduce the GARCH process:

First it recalls that the equation that described an ARCH(m) process was the following:

$$u_t = \sqrt{h_t} v_t$$

where $v_t$ is iid with zero mean and unit variance and where $h_t$ evolves according to

$$h_t = \xi + \alpha_1u_{t-1}^2+ \alpha_2u_{t-2}^2 + \dots+ \alpha_mu_{t-m}^2$$

Hamilton then invites us to imagine a more general process for wich the conditional variance depends on an infinite number of lags:

$$ h_t = \xi + \pi(L)u_t^2  $$

where $\pi(L) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \pi_j L^j$.

Hamilton then says that a natural idea is to parametrize $\pi(L)$ as the ratio of two finite polynomials as so

$$\pi(L) =\frac{ \alpha_1L^1+ \alpha_2L^2 + \dots + \alpha_mL^m}{1- \delta_1L^1-\delta_2L^2 - \dots -\delta_rL^r}$$

So why is this so natural?

Comment: Well, now you have a finite set of parameters where earlier you had an infinite number.

Answer (score 1):

As this is, I argue, not a question about GARCH per se, I have added an `ARMA` tag.

Infinite order polynomials arise as soon as lag polynomials are inverted.

Let me try to explain this via the more basic case of an ARMA process:

$$
Y_t=\phi_1Y_{t-1}+\phi_2Y_{t-2}+\ldots+\phi_pY_{t-p}+\epsilon_t+\;\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta_2\epsilon_{t-2}+\ldots+\theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}
$$
In lag operator notation, this can be written more compactly as
$$
\phi(L)Y_t=\theta(L)\epsilon_t
$$
where
$$
\phi(L)=1-\phi_1L-\phi_2L^2-\ldots-\phi_pL^p
$$
and
$$
\theta(L)=1+\theta_1L+\theta_2L^2+\ldots+\theta_qL^q
$$

If the roots of $\phi(z)=0$ lie outside the unit circle (and if $\phi(z)$ and $\theta(z)$ have no common roots), we can invert the AR polynomial to find
$$
Y_t=\phi(L)^{-1}\theta(L)\epsilon_t=:\psi(L)\epsilon_t
$$
The $\psi_i$ can be found *comparing coefficients*: From $\phi(L)Y_t=\theta(L)\epsilon_t$ and $Y_t=\psi(L)\epsilon_{t}$ we have $$\phi(L)Y_t=\phi(L)\psi(L)\epsilon_t=\theta(L)\epsilon_t$$
and hence $\phi(L)\psi(L)=\theta(L)$.

*Example*: ARMA(1,1)

We have
$$
(1-\phi L)(\psi_0+\psi_1L+\psi_2L^2+\psi_3L^3+\ldots)=1+\theta L
$$
and hence, by matching powers for a given power of $L$ on both sides of the equality,
\begin{align*}
\psi_0&=1\\
\psi_1-\phi\psi_0&=\theta\quad\Rightarrow\quad\psi_1=\phi+\theta\\
\psi_2-\phi\psi_1&=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\psi_2=\phi(\phi+\theta)
\end{align*}
and in general, $\psi_j=\phi^{j-1}(\phi+\theta)$ for $j\geqslant 1$.